# Verilog code for construction of 4x16 decoder using 3x8 decoder

Tags: verilog, xilinx, decoder, modelsim

This is my 3x8 verilog module:

```
module d3x8( output [7:0] d ,input [2:0] a, input e );
wire x,y,z;
not g1(z,a[0]);
not g2(y,a[1]);
not g3(x,a[2]);
and g4(d[0],x,y,z,e);
and g5(d[1],x,y,a[0],e);
and g6(d[2],x,a[1],z,e);
and g7(d[3],x,a[1],a[0],e);
and g8(d[4],a[2],y,z,e);
and g9(d[5],a[2],y,a[0],e);
and g10(d[6],a[2],a[1],z,e);
and g11(d[7],a[2],a[1],a[0],e);
endmodule
```

This is my 4x16 verilog module:

```
module d4x16(out, in,e);
output [15:0] out;     input [2:0] in;          input e;         
d3x8 d1(out[7:0],in[2:0],e);    
 d3x8 d2(out[15:8],in[2:0],~e);
 endmodule
```

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong? As I give the test bench values to run it does not show the right waveform according to the 4x16 truth table.

Comment: Show us how you tested it, and what you saw versus what you expected to see.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first off your input needs to be 4 bits instead of 3. Second, you need to use the 4th bit to generate the enables for the two decoders.